# How to install Weinre in windows7

Tags: android, mobile, remote-debugging, mobile-browser, weinre

Please help me in installing and debugging my mobile htmls from my machine using weinre.Lot of guys telling me how useful weinre is, but i am unable to find the way how to install it, please help me how to install weinre and debug using it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to use Weinre locally, here is the global process after install:
[Weinre does not find any target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761477/weinre-does-not-find-any-target)

More precisely here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16761649/79445

Answer (score 0):

When i try to search for the answer, i found one interesting link http://debug.phonegap.com/, there you have the weinre installed in that website.

What you need to do is:

1. open the link http://debug.phonegap.com/
2. Create your guid in the text box there.
3. then you see the script tag generated for your guid below.
4. copy paste that script tag in your mobile page where you want to test
5. open the page you want to test in the mobile browser
6. then come to the http://debug.phonegap.com/#yourguid.there you see the web inspector
7. debug it, simple.