# Weinre does not find any target

Tags: android, css, debugging, remote-debugging, weinre

Sorry for the newbie question, but I spent the whole day trying to figure out why the target list remains empty.

This is what I've done so far:

- Launched the Weinre host, bounded to my desktop ip adress
  (192.168.0.38)
- Checked it on Chrome : the host is bounded to
  192.68.0.38:8080
- Checked that the device is able to access to 192.168.0.38:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous
- White-listed both 192.168.0.38:8080 and 192.168.0.38 in config.xml
- Added the script call in the index.html

Still the target list remains empty when I launch the app on the device from ADT...

What should I do next?
Thanks!

__*_* EDIT

I tried the demo, and it's working!
So what makes the difference between calling the script from a demo file, or from the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it's working!

It seems I only had to wait a little bit after app initalization!??

Comment: I just had same problem and seemed to follow the exact same steps as @yako did. Fixed it by moving the target-script-min.js to the bottom of my html (just before body close), instead of having it in the head

Answer (score 1):

Turns out for me, the problem was that the mobile device silently switched over to another Wi-Fi network (than the one my computer was on), thus rendering the Weinre JS Script unreachable from within the app.

It's different than the issue described above (since, for Yako, the example scripts were working fine), but thought it could help somebody someday.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I kept trying to access a page anchor.  Apparently that doesn't work too well so I have to load the page first with no anchor, then add the anchor separately.

Answer (score 0):

For all of you who still have to use weinre and have the same problem, I just want to share my mistake:
I did not whitelist my IP-address in the config.xml
maybe some of you have the same mistake.